# Popup Setting is not working in <kendo-editor><kendo-toolbar>

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-editor, kendo-angular-ui

I have a very straight forward kendo-editor code like the one below

```
<div #containerRef>
    <kendo-editor style="height:500px">
          <kendo-toolbar>
            <kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist kendoEditorFormat></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
          </kendo-toolbar>
    </kendo-editor>
</div>
```

But my problem is that the dropdown is not showing inside the control but instead it's appending in the root component. I tried adding `[PopupSettings]="{appendTo: containerRef}"` in `<kendo-toolbar>` but still not working.

this is my code in .ts

```
@ViewChild('containerRef', { read: ViewContainerRef, static:true }) public containerRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

I confirmed in chrome developer tools that the popup is appending in the root component, that's why i use popupsettings but still it's not working.

Anyone experience the same issue?